# Преобразовать строку в число SQL c помощью таблицы DUAL

Tags: sql, oracle

Преобразуйте с помощью таблицы DUAL строку 'Aug/12/1986 06:54:07' в число ГГГГММДДччммсс

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Идиотское задание. DUAL просто позволяет превратить литерал в набор записей, не более.

Comment: На ней удобно пробовать функции конвертации зато. Поэтому во многих курсах по SQL - в заданиях она используется.

Comment: спасибо большое, Konst. Очень помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('Aug/12/1986 06:54:07', 'MONTH/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS') as datenum from dual;
```

проверить можно тут: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=33ae7118f7c1977d68504391515eb4b2

Comment: Спасибо большое Konst, очень помогли.